# Hibernate search, convert byte[] to List<LuceneWork>

Tags: jms, lucene, hibernate-search

As of Hibernate Search 3.1.1, when one wanted to send an indexed entity to a JMS queue for further processing, in the `onMessage()` method of the processing MDB was enough to apply a cast to obtain the list of LuceneWork, e.g

```
List<LuceneWork> queue = (List<LuceneWork>) objectMessage.getObject();
```

But in version 4.2.0 this is no longer an option as `objectMessage.getObject()` returns a `byte[]`.

How could I deserialize this `byte[]` into `List<LuceneWork>`?

I've inspected the message and saw that I have the value for `JMSBackendQueueTask.INDEX_NAME_JMS_PROPERTY`.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend [AbstractJMSHibernateSearchController](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/master/hibernate-search-orm/src/main/java/org/hibernate/search/backend/impl/jms/AbstractJMSHibernateSearchController.java) and have it deal with these details, or have a look at its source which contains:

```
indexName = objectMessage.getStringProperty(JmsBackendQueueTask.INDEX_NAME_JMS_PROPERTY);
indexManager = factory.getAllIndexesManager().getIndexManager(indexName);
if (indexManager == null) {
    log.messageReceivedForUndefinedIndex(indexName);
    return;
}
queue = indexManager.getSerializer().toLuceneWorks((byte[]) objectMessage.getObject());
indexManager.performOperations(queue, null);
```

Compared to older versions 3.x there are two main design differences to keep in mind:

- The Serializer service is pluggable so it needs to be looked up
- Each index (identified by name) can have an independent backend

The serialization is now performed (by default) using Apache Avro as newer Lucene classes are not Serializable.